# Not Found "/lobby/" django-channels routing error

Tags: javascript, django, django-channels

routing.py

```
from channels import include, route
from chat import consumers
from . import game_consumers

channel_routing = [
    #game routing
    route('websocket.connect', game_consumers.ws_connect_lobby, path=r"^/lobby/$"),
    route('websocket.receive', game_consumers.ws_receive_lobby, path=r"^/lobby/$"),
    route('websocket.disconnect', game_consumers.ws_disconnect_lobby, path=r"^/lobby/$"),
```

app.js

```
Websocket = {
    lobby_socket: null,
    setup_ws_lobby : function(){
        Websocket.lobby_socket = new ReconnectingWebSocket(Websocket.ws_scheme + '://' + window.location.host + '/lobby/');
        Websocket.lobby_socket.onmessage = function(message) {
            //nothing yet
        };
    },
}
Websocket.setup_ws_lobby();
```

The url is `127.0.0.1:8000/game`. `Websocket.setup_ws_lobby()` is executed on page load. I don't see what I'm doing wrong. I get the error `Not Found: /lobby/` in my `python manage.py runserver` console when I load the page. My routes are clearly set and my js setup seems to route to those routes. Can anyone help? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The code is valid; it was a version issue. Upgraded to 1.1.8 and it worked

Comment: Which packet did you upgrade?